# Arrays.sort(object[]) is not throwing classcastexception

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, classcastexception, comparable

Code:

```
public class CompareTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList list =  new ArrayList();
        (list).add(new CompareTest());  


        Arrays.sort(list.toArray()); //Does not throw Exception , why ?
        Collections.sort(list);   //throws ClassCastException
    }

}
```

As per Java Doc:
[Arrays#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Sorts the specified array of objects into ascending order, according to the 
  natural ordering of its elements. **All elements in the array must
implement the Comparable interface**.

Why does [Arrays#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) , doesnt throw `ClassCastException` as stated by JavaDoc ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the source code of `Arrays.sort()` has this shortcut :

```
    int nRemaining  = hi - lo;
    if (nRemaining < 2)
        return;  // Arrays of size 0 and 1 are always sorted
```

So it doesn't bother checking if the elements of the array implement Comparable, because it doesn't have to sort an array that has only one element.

Note that the javadoc doesn't *guarantee* that a ClassCastException is thrown.

Comment: Interesting - the same thing was "fixed" in TreeMap in Java 7, but apparently not in Arrays...

Comment: So javadoc can be deceiving.

Answer (score 2):

Because it has only one element...And the `Array.sort()` will end without sorting if there are elements less than 2

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that list has only one elemnt,the compareTo method never invoked in Arrays.sort,so the element is never cast to Comparable.

but it's invoked anyway in Collections.sort:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
Object[] a = list.toArray();
Arrays.sort(a);
ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
    i.next();
    i.set((T)a[j]);
}
}
```

all elemnt is casting to T which extends from Comparable